# Simple Listview emulator-5554 null error

Tags: android, listview

I want to get the textvalue to be changed to listview value when i click the listview.
I couldn't do this. Please help me.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listvalue"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:text="@string/listval" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@id/textvalue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtval" />
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stopBtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] songlist={"Green","Yellow","Black","White","Red"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,R.layout.activity_main, R.id.txtvalue, songlist);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you get your answer?

Comment: List is not visible now.

Comment: see my answer may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace this.

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@id/textvalue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtval" />

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_main, R.id.txtvalue, songlist);
```

some useful link.

http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/09/simple-listview-example-in-android.html

if you find any trouble then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting the TextView and setting the value.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textvalue);
    tv.setText(item);
}
```

Comment: fatal exception unable to activity Your content must have a listview android.R.id.list .

Comment: Change the id of your list from android:id="@+id/listvalue" to android:id="@android:id/list"

Answer (score 0):

just use below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

            String[] songlist={"Green","Yellow","Black","White","Red"};
            TextView tv;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textvalue);
                //String[] songlist={"Green","Yellow","Black","White","Red"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.Layout.simple_list_item_1, songlist);

               setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

          @Override
          protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          String item  = songlist[position];
          Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          tv.setText(item);
         }
    }
```

in layout file: replace this line `android:id="@id/textvalue"` to this `android:id="@+id/textvalue"`

Comment: List is empty when i execute in the emulator.

Comment: change this line : ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.Layout.simple_list_item_1, songlist);

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
ListView listView=getListView();
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```